# KeyError Codes from User Input

Tags: python, dictionary, user-input

Good Evening All,

I have been working on my first self directed project and have run into a bit of a snag.  The program calculates what a character would have to roll to hit another based on their THAC0 and AC.  The two scores in question are kept in a pair of dictionaries.  If something is entered that is not in the dictionary I want the program to let whoever is operating it know.  I've managed to get it to produce an error code, but I still get a KeyError.  How do I get it to stop doing that?

```
defender = input("Who are they attacking?")
dict_thaco = {"Serena" : 19, "Morris" : 19}
if aggressor in dict_thaco:
    pass
else:
    print("I don't know that attacker")
dict_ac = {"Serena" : 6, "Morris" : -1}
if defender in dict_ac:
    pass
else:
    print("I don't know that defender")
def thaco_calc(thaco, ac):
    to_hit = thaco - ac
    return to_hit
aggressor_thaco = dict_thaco[aggressor]
defender_ac = dict_ac[defender]
hit = thaco_calc(aggressor_thaco, defender_ac)
print(aggressor + " would need to roll a " + str(hit) + " to hit " + defender + ".")
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need something like

```
...
try:
    aggressor_thaco = dict_thaco[aggressor]
    defender_ac = dict_ac[defender]
    hit = thaco_calc(aggressor_thaco, defender_ac)
    print(aggressor + " would need to roll a " + str(hit) + " to hit " + defender + ".")
except KeyError as e:
    print(e)
```